# How can I set html5 data attribute for the cell

Tags: dhtmlx-scheduler

Lib: DHTMLX Scheduler

I need to set html5 data attribute to any cell in the timeline view.
No problem to set cell class, but what about the data-attr?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes in the source code (dhtmlxscheduler_timeline.js extension) and add data attribute while the HTML for cell is created.